# How do you create a dummy variable with multiple columns of ID code and dates in R?

Tags: r, variables, multiple-columns, dummy-variable

I have the following data:

`ID month year
1    2   2002
1    1   2003
1    3   2003
2    2   2017
2    2   2017
3    1   2012
3    1   2002
3    2   2014
3    2   2014
4    1   2003
5    2   2002
5    5   2015`

And I want to create the following dummy variable:

`ID month year    1st   2nd   3rd
1    2   2002     1     0     0

1    1   2003     0     1     0
1    3   2003     0     0     1
2    2   2017     1     0     0
2    2   2017     1     0     0
3    1   2012     1     0     0
3    1   2002     1     0     0
3    2   2014     0     1     0
3    2   2014     0     1     0
4    1   2003     1     0     0
5    2   2002     1     0     0
5    5   2015     0     1     0`

except with five columns (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th)

Progress:

I combined the date details into one, and used the following function

`df$newcolumn <- ave(df$ID, df$date, FUN=seq_along)`

and then generated a dummy variable for each based on the counter.
however, this function counts the repeating dates as unique, which I don't want.

Note: there are thousands of data points & IDs

Comment: the expected output indicates whether the date (of occurance) per ID is the first, second, third. There are multiple of each date because of other relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for anyone else who needs it:

`df$obs <- with(df, ave(df$date, df$ID, FUN=function(x) cumsum(!duplicated(x))))`

which created a count, and I simply created dummy columns off of that count